# How to implement flatpickr when using cocoon in edit action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem, flatpickr

I'm using the flatpickr calendar in a nested cocoon form. Everything functions as expected when creating a new form, but when I want to edit an existing form:

- The first flatpickr field renders correctly
- Adding a new flatpickr field with cocoon renders correctly
- Every other existing flatpickr field after the 1st one **does not** render.

edit_form

```
<div class="form-container col col-sm-6 col-lg-12">
  <%= simple_form_for [@accommodation_category, @extra_guest] do |f|%>
  <div class="options-form">

  <div class="options-form-item">
  <h4 class="p-3">Price for guest per period:</h4 class="m-3">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :extra_guest_prices do |price| %>
    <div class="reservation-details">
      <%= render 'extra_guest_price_fields', f: price %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <div>
      <%= link_to_add_association f, :extra_guest_prices do %>
      <div class="option-add-option-price">
        <div class="prices-border">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another period
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-6"> <%= f.button :submit, "Save new option", class: "create-reservation-btn"%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript for edit_form

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    const startDateInput = $(document).find("#first_date")
    const endDateInput = $(document).find("#second_date")

    if (startDateInput && endDateInput) {
    flatpickr(startDateInput, {
      format: "d-m-Y",
      altFormat: "d-m-Y",
      altInput: true,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, selectedDate) {
      if (selectedDate === '') {
        endDateInput.disabled = true;
      }
      let minDate = selectedDates[0];
      minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
      endDateCalendar.set('minDate', minDate);
      endDateInput.disabled = false;
    }
  });
    const endDateCalendar =
    flatpickr(endDateInput, {
      format: "d-m-Y",
      altFormat: "d-m-Y",
      altInput: true,
      },
      );
  };
});
</script>
```

extra_guest_price_fields

```
  <div class="nested-fields border-bottom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-6"><%= f.input :price, placeholder: "e.g. 12.99" %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6"><%= f.input :weekend_extra, placeholder: "Price on top of normal price"  %></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-sm-6"><%= f.input :start_date,
          as: :string,
          label:"Start date",
          placeholder: "From",
          wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
          input_html:{ id: "first_date"} %></div>
      <div class="col col-sm-6"><%= f.input :end_date,
          as: :string,
          label:"End date",
          placeholder: "to",
          wrapper_html: { class: "inline_field_wrapper" },
          input_html:{ id: "second_date"} %></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-sm-6 option-price-delete">
      <%= link_to_remove_association f do %>
      <i class="fas fa-trash"> Delete price</i>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, added_guest_price_form){


  const startDateInput = $(added_guest_price_form.find("#first_date"))
  const endDateInput = $(added_guest_price_form.find("#second_date"))

  if (startDateInput && endDateInput) {

    flatpickr(startDateInput, {
      format: "d-m-Y",
      altFormat: "d-m-Y",
      altInput: true,

    onChange: function(selectedDates, selectedDate) {
      if (selectedDate === '') {
        endDateInput.disabled = true;
      }
      let minDate = selectedDates[0];
      minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
      endDateCalendar.set('minDate', minDate);
      endDateInput.disabled = false;
    }
  });
    const endDateCalendar =
      flatpickr(endDateInput, {
        format: "d-m-Y",
        altFormat: "d-m-Y",
        altInput: true,
        },
      );
};
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not show the partial `extra_guest_price_fields` I can only guess, but in your js you refer to `#first_date` and `#second_date`. This sounds like using html-ids for repeating elements, as you are bound to have more than 1 of those pairs. HTML id's are supposed to exist only once on a page, so using that selector it will stop on the first found.

I propose you use html classes like `.first_date` and `.second_date` and adjust your js accordingly and then it should work.

Comment: thank you for the response and my apologies for not showing ``` extra_guest_price_fields```.  I edited my question and incorporated the file for future reference. I incorporated your feedback and changed the id's to classes and now everything works. Thank you so much!